# Pythonic way to cut specific elements from numpy array

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, numpy

I have a Python list (numpy array) and another list which contains the indices for the location of values from the first array which I want to keep.

Is there a Pythonic way to do this?
I know numpy.delete, but I want to keep the elements and not delete them.

Comment: What have you tried? What's your existing solution that you think that may not be "Pythonic" enough?

Comment: @woozyking
option 1: iterating over the main array and checking if that index is there in the second array or not (we can convert the second list to a map for O(1) lookup).


option 2: make a copy of first array and then deleting using numpy.delete and then taking the difference between the original list and new (smaller) list - but this will not retain the original order.

Comment: That's wonderful to have more than one option. However it'd be even better for you to actually demonstrate them as (sample) code so others can help you more effectively.

Comment: @woozyking I'm not sure if a (sample) code will help. 
My question is not about how to efficiently implement what I wrote, but if there's a fundamentally different way to achieve this (perhaps in a single line) which I am missing.

Comment: I'm not sure what your starting conditions are. Do you want to act on a Python `list` or a `numpy.array`? Obviously, it cannot be both at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most pythonic way is probably also the most straightforward one:

```
a = np.array([2,5,6,3,6,3,45,6])
b = [0,3,4,7] # indices that you need to keep
c = a[b]
```

or, if you do not need `a` any longer:

```
a = a[b]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new list with the values that you want to keep.

```
a = np.array([2,5,6,3,6,3,45,6])
b = [0,3,4,7] #indices that yo need to keep
c = [a[i] for i in b]
```

Comment: Well, this is more cleaner than any of the approaches I mentioned above. Thanks for this!

Comment: Why not just `a[b]`?  Much more efficient to use `numpy` indexing if working with numpy arrays

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use just `c=a[b]` as this is the Python way to take the values from array a.